# Showing Data in Google Maps Drawing

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps in a web page. On that map, a user can draw a circle. I have the following:

```
var myManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
  drawingControl: true,
  drawingControlOptions: {
    drawingModes: [
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    ]
  },
  circleOptions: {
    clickable: true,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true,
    zIndex: 1
  }
});
myManager.setMap(new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("roadMap"), {}););
myManager.setDrawingMode(null);

google.maps.event.addListener(myManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) {
        });
```

As the user is drawing, I want to show them the radius of the circle. In other words, it may say 1.25 miles. Then as the circle grows, it may go to 2.0 miles. Is there a way to do this with Google Maps? If so, how? I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the circle until the `circlecomplete` event fires.  Once that happens you can display the radius, and add a `radius_changed` listener to it.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syg9kok0/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var circles = [];

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var myManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
      ]
    },
    circleOptions: {
      clickable: true,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  myManager.setMap(map);
  myManager.setDrawingMode(null);

  google.maps.event.addListener(myManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function() {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "circle center = " + circle.getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + " radius = " + circle.getRadius().toFixed(2) + " meters";
    });
    circles.push(circle);
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "circle center = " + circle.getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + " radius = " + circle.getRadius().toFixed(2) + " meters";
  });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style=" border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```